# Load and Save State in UWP

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

What is the status for supporting UWP? The documentation walkthroughs mention Win 8.1 only and in VS 2015 when trying to connect to a mobile service I get a "project type not supported" in a Win 10 Universal app.

To unblock me, I was thinking to use a dummy Win 8.1 Universal app, connect to a mobile service and then copy what's generated by the tool in my Win 10 Universal app. Is that the right approach?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Your subject line speaks of saving state, but in the body if your message it sounds like you are talking about web services.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. All about app lifecycle here.

[A Developer's Guide to Windows 10: (13) Application Lifecycle](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10/13)